# UILabel inside cell in UITableView is always null (two cell prototypes)

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I am trying to populate cells in table view ( I have two custom types of cells with with different elements created in storyboard, with identifiers "info_cell" and "person_cell", on segmented control above UITableView I decide what to load [tableView reload]). When I try to access UILabels inside cell I get that labels are null.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = (viewType == INFO_VIEW) ? @"info_cell" :@"person_cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if(viewType == INFO_VIEW){
        NSLog(@"INFO = %@", info_text_some_string);
        UILabel *lblInfo = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
        [lblInfo setText:info_text_some_string];
    }
    else{
        // there is part for person
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Same code works when I have just one prototype cell inside table (UITableView is inside UIVewController). What can be problem here, I have checked 100 times: cell identifiers are OK, label tag is 200.

This is action for UISegmentControl

```
- (IBAction)changeView:(id)sender {
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (selectedSegment == 0) {
        viewType = INFO_VIEW;
    }
    else{
        viewType = PERSON_VIEW;
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

I have added  and necessary methods for tableView and connect delegate i datasource.
Does anyone have any idea why it is null ?

Comment: can you post the solution which worked for you, as i am facing similar issue..

Answer (score 0):

Try this usually i follow this process whenever i go with custom cell in **CellRorRowAtIndexPath**

```
   if(!cell)
    {
        cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        //customcell is your UITableViewCell created by you in ur xib
        NSData *archivedData =[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:customcell];
        cell =[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedData];

    }
    if(viewType ==INFO_VIEW)
     {
    [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200] setText:@"you text"];
     }
  else{
        // person view....
      }
```

This way your collecting all your elements of your cell and setting value for it. share your results please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have subclass your UITableViewCells correctly (I use InfoCell and PersonCell for example), you can try this:

```
if(viewType == INFO_VIEW)
{
    InfoCell *cell = (InfoCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"info_cell"];
    // do your stuff for info here
}
else if(viewType == PERSON_VIEW)
{
    PersonCell *cell = (PersonCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"person_cell"];
    // do your stuff for person here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not do something like this?

```
[[cell textLabel] setText: @"text goes here"];
```

And skip the UILabel part?

Comment: I added now, it is custom types cells with different elements on it